# How to match everything except for digits followed by a space and ONLY digits followed by a space?

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

## The problem

What the header says, basically. Given a string, I need to extract from it everything that is *not* a leading number followed by a space. So, given this string

```
"420 species of grass"
```

I would like to get

```
"species of grass"
```

But, given a string with a number not in the beginning, like so

```
"The clock says it is 420"
```

or a string with a number not followed by a space, like so

```
"It is 420 already"
```

I would like to get back the same string, with the number preserved

```
"The clock says it is 420"
"It is 420 already"
```

## What I have tried

Matching a leading number followed by a space works as expected:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("420 species of grass", "^\\d+(?=\\s)")
[[1]]
[1] "420"
```

```
> str_extract_all("The clock says it is 420", "^\\d+(?=\\s)")
[[1]]
character(0)
```

```
> str_extract_all("It is 420 already", "^\\d+(?=\\s)")
[[1]]
character(0)
```

But, when I try to match *anything but* a leading number followed by a space, it doesn't:

```
> str_extract_all("420 species of grass", "[^(^\\d+(?=\\s))]+")
[[1]]
[1] "species" "of"      "grass"
```

```
> str_extract_all("The clock says it is 420", "[^(^\\d+(?=\\s))]+")
[[1]]
[1] "The"   "clock" "says"  "it"    "is"
```

```
> str_extract_all("It is 420 already", "[^(^\\d+(?=\\s))]+")
[[1]]
[1] "It"      "is"      "already"
```

It seems this regex matches anything but digits AND spaces instead.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not just **match** what you want and replace that with an empty string instead?

Comment: Your post is confusing as per your words and what is your expected output. You say you don't want to capture string if it has number followed by space(s) then how come you want this string `It is 420 already` intact? As per your samples and expected output, you don't want to include the digit(s) followed by space(s) if they are at the very start of string. Is that correct?

Comment: @IbrahimNajjar, well I didn't think of that, but it would be a perfectly acceptable solution. Buuut, I would really like to know why matching *anything but* doesn't work with my regex. Granted, I did't make it clear that I would like to know that, so yeah. Thank you!

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi yep, you got it right. I've made a few edits, hopefully the question is more articulate now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is by removing the numbers instead of extracting the desired pattern:

```
library(stringr)

strings <- c("420 species of grass", "The clock says it is 420", "It is 420 already")
str_remove(strings, pattern = "^\\d+\\s")

[1] "species of grass"         "The clock says it is 420" "It is 420 already"
```

Comment: This works, but I would like to know why my regex isn't working too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think @Douglas's answer is more concise, however, I guess your actual case would be more complicated and you may want to check `?regexpr` which can identify the starting position of your specific pattern.

A method using `for` loop is below:

```r
list <- list("420 species of grass",
               "The clock says it is 420",
               "It is 420 already")

extract <- function(x) {
  y <- vector('list', length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (regexpr("420", x[[i]])[[1]] > 1) {
      y[[i]] <- x[[i]]
       }
    else{
      y[[i]] <- substr(x[[i]], (regexpr(" ", x[[i]])[[1]] + 1), nchar(x[[i]]))

    }
  }
  return(y)
}
```

```r
> extract(list)
[[1]]
[1] "species of grass"

[[2]]
[1] "The clock says it is 420"

[[3]]
[1] "It is 420 already"
```

Comment: This works, but I don't completely understand why. I guess I really need to to take a good look at `?regexpr`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way out is to replace any digits followed by spaces that occur right from the start of string using this regex,

```
^\d+\s+
```

with empty string.

**[Regex Demo using substitution](https://regex101.com/r/Uk1adu/1)**

[Sample R code using sub demo](https://rextester.com/YTBZ84661)

```
sub("^\\d+\\s+", "", "420 species of grass")
sub("^\\d+\\s+", "", "The clock says it is 420")
sub("^\\d+\\s+", "", "It is 420 already")
```

Prints,

```
[1] "species of grass"
[1] "The clock says it is 420"
[1] "It is 420 already"
```

Alternative way to achieve same using matching, you can use following regex and capture contents of group1,

```
^(?:\d+\s+)?(.*)$
```

**[Regex Demo using match](https://regex101.com/r/Uk1adu/2)**

Also, anything you place inside a character set looses its special meaning like positive lookahead inside it `[^(^\\d+(?=\\s))]+` and simply behaves as a literal, so your regex becomes incorrect.

**Edit:**

Although solution using `sub` is better but in case you want match based solution using R codes, you need to use `str_match` instead of `str_extract_all` and for accessing group1 contents you need to use `[,2]`

**[R Code Demo using match](https://rextester.com/RVBFT56272)**

```
library(stringr)

print(str_match("420 species of grass", "^(?:\\d+\\s+)?(.*)$")[,2])
print(str_match("The clock says it is 420", "^(?:\\d+\\s+)?(.*)$")[,2])
print(str_match("It is 420 already", "^(?:\\d+\\s+)?(.*)$")[,2])
```

Prints,

```
[1] "species of grass"
[1] "The clock says it is 420"
[1] "It is 420 already"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on anything inside a character set losing it's special meaning (like lookahead)? It seems like something that I need to learn. Or maybe tell me where I can read up on this?

Comment: Also, your solution with replacement works, but the alternative using matching doesn't, at least for me. I.e. `str_extract_all("420 species of grass", "^(?:\\d+\\s+)?(.*)$")` returns `"420 species of grass"`, with the number preserved.

Comment: @vvvvasily: Hey, updated my answer with R codes for match based solution. But I'll suggest to prefer `sub` based solution.

Comment: that works, thanks. And thanks to you mentioning character sets I understand why my regex was wrong now. But why do you say I should prefer `sub()` approach? Are ICU regular expressions (which `stringr` employs) inferior in some way?

Comment: @vvvvasily: No no nothing like that. Just said that because for `sub` you don't even need to import a lib as well as it sounded more intuitive to me. But feel free you choose the one that suits you better.